# Identifying Defunct YouTube links

Tags: youtube, links

Suppose we have stored a YouTube link in our favorites or folder, without anything to identify what the link might have been, as the link at YouTube has now removed/unavailable after some unknown period of time.

Is there a (slim) chance a search bot will later detect any text associated with the vid to help identify what it was?

Answer (score 1):

The method below may not be reliable if the [youtube urls are re-used](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/98085/does-youtube-reuse-old-defunct-video-ids-to-new-videos?newreg=483efd5f0e344b2db45909f4264ecc42):

Tried separating two components of the link as such:

```
youtube identifier
```

and pasting them in a browser searchbox.

Was lucky in a particular instance with this [removed link](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=youtube%20Hbor3fQtVfQ&oq=youtube%20Hbor3fQtVfQ&aqs=chrome..69i57.13170j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)- only because it was directly siphoned off elsewhere (but still unusable).
But most common browsers will remove matching text- the [Deep Web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_web) may handle it differently.